# Why does Pandas in IDLE take so long to import?

Tags: python, pandas

I found that pandas in Python took a rather long time to import, so I ran timeit comparing it to the import time for other libraries:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("import math")
0.21986381600000016
>>> timeit.timeit("import tkinter")
0.23442026200000043
>>> timeit.timeit("import pandas")
0.9272596610000008
```

Why does it take so load to import compared to other libraries

Comment: because pandas is so much bigger.

Comment: I think this has been getting worse and worse, start of 2023 this is what I'm getting:
>>> timeit.timeit("import math")
0.15023570000000142
>>> timeit.timeit("import tkinter")
0.30910809999999955
>>> timeit.timeit("import pandas")
4.274847900000001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` means that Python interpreter have to execute the full code from the imported module (and probably from all nested imports, too).

It's not the flaw of the IDLE. For IDLE I obtained approximately the same result as you, but for PyCharm with IPython interpreter they are here:

```
In[12]: timeit.timeit("import math")
Out[12]: 0.9957449290086515

In[13]: timeit.timeit("import tkinter")
Out[13]: 1.5823995640384965

In[14]: timeit.timeit("import pandas")
Out[14]: 1.012685161025729
```

Of course, it depends on versions of imported modules, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really large library in comparison to math or tkinter